# Access images in Mint 17.2

Tags: linux-mint, desktop-environment, wallpaper

Linux Mint 17.2 has lots of magnificent images that appear on the login screen.  I would like to use these images for other things, such as the desktop background.  Can anyone tell me where I might locate the image files in the system?